# Eclipse Java Cucumber debug - how can I configure and run debug in cucumber maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, cucumber, maven-2

How can I configure Eclipse to run debug on a cucumber project?
I put breakpoint in given condition from specific "Step" java class and I have created maven build profile like as picture attachment but debugging doesn't work.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have resolved by putting on the goals: -Dmaven.surefire.debug test -DforkCount=0 test

Comment: This was a huge help, you should add this comment as answer and mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running it by maven commond like:

```
mvn clean install
```

But you need to run it using junit or testng.

Put an debug point in your step defination and run the project as junit/testng in debug section

Answer (score 0):

You need to use install TestNG or Junit testing frameworks and use them in the run configurations will help to debug the cucumber test.

For TestNG, once after you install the software using install new software in Eclipse. In the TestNG Run Configurations give the Testng.xml file in the Suite field