# Intellij - maven runner does not stop at breakpoints in debug mode

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have java cucumber project. In Intellij - maven runner does not stop at breakpoints in debug mode.
Do you know what shoulb be changed ?

Here is the link to the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdG5v.jpg)
[image: IntelliJ-maven-run-config]

I Intellij I click green icon "debug" at the top of the screen and tests starts but does not stop at breakpoints.

Comment: Where are your breakpoints set ?

Comment: in page object model

Comment: Did you muted breakpoints? Its icon in the debugging window is a red circle with a white line running from the bottom-left to the top-right through it.

Comment: easiest: don't use maven(..for this, but "debug test in IDE" ..as (poorly) described [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/debugging/?lang=java)), when with maven, (i fear) you have to stick with https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html ... duplicate(unanswerd): https://stackoverflow.com/q/52221703/592355

Comment: Breakpoints are red, but icon to run debug mode is green

Comment: if not maven runner - how to run this in junit runner in debug mode with maven options ?

Comment: Why did you show us a compilation run configuration (`mvn verify` desdn't run your program)? Do you want to debug the java compiler? :D

Comment: I want the test to stop at red breakpoints in java code

Comment: for the surefire+forked case, also consider: you will need a (maven) "run(test) configuration" + a (debug) "attach configuration" (remote/attached debugging!)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your breakpoint ?

Comment: `> how to debug junit?` Click the gutter on the left side of your test method (or -class) and select debug instead of run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that you are using a Maven Goal to debug your Project.

If you want to keep using Maven for debugging check Maven's [(1)](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html) and IDEA's  [(1)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) [(2)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/attaching-to-local-process.html) documentation on this topic.

You can make the debugging process much easier, if you use a dedicated Cucumber Run/Debug Config:

[image: dedicated Cucumber Run/Debug Config]